# Showing Consecutive images on a QLabel PyQt4

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt, pyqt4, qpixmap

I'm trying to show consecutive images on a QLabel
the images are numbered from 0000000 to 0000199
the problem is that the num variable prints empty string

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
import sys, time

class Animation(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Animation, self).__init__(parent)

        self.resize(QSize(720, 480))

        self.imageViewer = QLabel(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.imageViewer)

        startBtn = QPushButton("start", self)
        startBtn.clicked.connect(self.start)
        self.statusBar().addWidget(startBtn)

    def start(self):
        i = 0
        while 1:
            num = ("0" * (len(str(i)) - 7)) + str(i)
            name = "frame" + num + ".png"
            print ("0" * (len(str(i)) - 7))
            self.imageViewer.setPixmap(QPixmap(name))
            if i == 199:
                break
            i += 1
            time.sleep(1)

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
test = Animation()
test.show()
app.exec_()
```

Please help

Comment: No I Changed my mind

Answer (score 0):

`len(str(i)) - 7` returns a negative number. You need to swap it around:

`num = '0' * (7-len(str(i))) + str(i)`

Comment: I think the problem is not in the num because the images still doesn't appear and the app freezes

Comment: You need to work with [QThreads](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/thread-basics.html). The main Thread is only updating the User Interface when it is ready. Therefore you need another thread telling the mainthread to swap the image.